# How to get index/data of html table generated by foreach

Tags: php, html, xml

I load a xml file and loop on this to generate an html table. On each line of the table, I have two icones update and delete. 
When I click on the icone delete (for example), I want to get the index of the line or any information of the line in order to process delete the node in my xml file.
I try with echo $number by passing parameter to php function but the GET is empty in the php file.

Do you know how can I get it please ? Thank in advance.

```
       <table>
        <?php
        foreach($participants as $participant)
        {
        $number = $participant->number;
        $name = $participant->name;
        $note = $participant->note;
        $sexe = $participant->sexe;
        $group = $participant->group;
        $adjust = $participant->adjust;
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td align="center"><?php echo($number) ?></td>
            <td align="left" style="padding-left:10px"><?php echo($name) ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo($note) ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo($sexe)  ?></td>
            <td align="center"><?php echo($group) ?></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <a href="php/updateParticipant.php5"><img src="images/migatiEditUser20x20.jpg"></a>
              <a href="php/deleteParticipant.php5?number=<?php echo($number) ?>"><img src="images/migati_cancel16x16.png"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php }?>
    </table>
```

`deleteParticipant.php
<?php
echo ($_GET['number']);
?>`

Comment: I'd just have a counter inside your foreach and then use the value

Comment: Yep but when the foreach is finished .... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   <table>
    <?php
    foreach($participants as $participant)
    {
    $number = $participant->number;
    $name = $participant->name;
    $note = $participant->note;
    $sexe = $participant->sexe;
    $group = $participant->group;
    $adjust = $participant->adjust;
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $number; ?></td>
        <td align="left" style="padding-left:10px"><?php echo $name; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $note; ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $sexe;  ?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $group; ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
          <a href="php/updateParticipant.php5"><img src="images/migatiEditUser20x20.jpg"></a>
          <a href="php/deleteParticipant.php5?number=<?php echo $number; ?>"><img src="images/migati_cancel16x16.png"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }?>
</table>
```

and on your `deleteParticipant.php` use:

```
<?php echo $_GET['number']; ?>
```

Comment: So `$number = $participant->number;` just didn't got any content.. Where dit you get the numbers from? Can you add the code of that to your question?

Comment: COOL it works now, just I clicked on the line that the tag number was absent, SORRY. Thanks A lot.

Comment: Just one more question, if I put on the same line a checkbox, so my table have a multiple checkbox, how can I get the list of the lines checked ?

Comment: Ask another question for that :) This one can be closed. To accept my answer, just click on the green checkmark beside of my post :)

Answer (score -1):

You have to know how get works. Adjust the code as `deleteParticipent.php?number= <?php echo $number; ?>` then from that file. You will recieve it as `$_GET['number']`

Comment: Yes, that is the way I process, but echo('$_GET['number']) display nothing !

Comment: It works like that, just I make mistake on one line, thankyou.